# Decreasing the topAnchor of an UIView by scrolling the tableView inside it

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

I have a view that there is `tableView` inside this view. This View is in the bottom  of an `UIViewController`, and there is an another view is in top of it. But I set the top anchor of tableView View to the top side the screen that I can change it when I need - see the screenshot

I want when tableView is scrolling, the top anchor decrease.
For this I did that in the `UIView` that contains `TableView`

```
  func scrollViewDidScroll(_ scrollView: UIScrollView) {
 
    let offset = scrollView.contentOffset.y
    scrollView.bounces = false
    eventHandler?(.scrollViewDidScroll(offset: offset))
}
```

With this `eventHandler` I send the offset the parent `UIViewController`
And then use this function to reduce the the topAnchor

```
private func handleOffsetScrolling(offset: CGFloat) {
    let constant =  taskViewHeight - offset
    if constant > 0 {
        todosTableTopAnchor.constant = taskViewHeight - offset
        view.layoutIfNeeded()
    }
}
```

the `taskViewHeight`is the height of the second view in the top. It works well as expected, but during the decreasing the `topAnchor`, the tableView also scrolling, I want to prevent that. I mean the tableView should not scroll until the view reach to the top and then it scrolls.
and when scrolling to the top of tableView again, it should increasing the top anchor and move the tableView view to its original position.
I just want to prevent tableView scrolling during the increasing and decreasing the top anchor.

Is there any way to do that?
Thanks

[image]

Comment: Do you want the **height** of the green view to change -- to "squeeze" it? Or do you want it to slide up and out of view?

Comment: Slide up the view, the green one will be under the blue one

Comment: Are you laying this out in Storyboard? Or via code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You almost certainly don't want to put these views in a scroll view.

To get the (blue) table view to "slide up on-top-of" the green view, you can constrain the Top of both views to the same Y-position. Then set the table view's `contentInset.top` to the height of the green view, and start with the table view's `.contentOffset.y` at *minus* the height of the green view.

Here'a a really quick example:

```
class ViewController: UIViewController, UITableViewDataSource, UITableViewDelegate {
    
    let greenHeaderView = UIView()
    let tableView = UITableView()
    
    // let's make the green view height: 100-points
    let greenHeight: CGFloat = 100.0
    
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        // let's add a label to the green view so we can see what goes on
        let label = UILabel()
        label.textAlignment = .center
        label.text = "This is sample text for the Header View"
        label.textColor = .yellow
        
        greenHeaderView.backgroundColor = .systemGreen

        label.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        greenHeaderView.addSubview(label)

        greenHeaderView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        tableView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        view.addSubview(greenHeaderView)
        view.addSubview(tableView)
        
        let g = view.safeAreaLayoutGuide
        NSLayoutConstraint.activate([
            
            greenHeaderView.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: g.topAnchor),
            greenHeaderView.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: g.leadingAnchor),
            greenHeaderView.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: g.trailingAnchor),

            greenHeaderView.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: greenHeight),
            
            label.centerXAnchor.constraint(equalTo: greenHeaderView.centerXAnchor),
            label.centerYAnchor.constraint(equalTo: greenHeaderView.centerYAnchor),
            
            tableView.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: g.topAnchor),
            tableView.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: g.leadingAnchor),
            tableView.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: g.trailingAnchor),
            tableView.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: g.bottomAnchor),
            
        ])
        
        tableView.register(UITableViewCell.self, forCellReuseIdentifier: "c")
        tableView.dataSource = self
        tableView.delegate = self
    
        tableView.backgroundColor = .clear

        tableView.contentInset.top = greenHeight
        tableView.contentOffset.y = -greenHeight

    }
    
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return 30
    }
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let c = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "c", for: indexPath)
        c.textLabel?.text = "\(indexPath)"
        return c
    }
    
}
```

---

**Edit** - *based on comment...*

If you have interactive UI elements in the green "Header" view, we need to add the green view **after** we add the table view.

Then, we can change the height of that green view as the table view scrolls.

Importantly, we set `.clipsToBounds = true` on the green view, so its subviews do not show outside of its bounds.

Here is that same example, with minor modifications:

```
class ViewController: UIViewController, UITableViewDataSource, UITableViewDelegate {
    
    let greenHeaderView = UIView()
    let tableView = UITableView()
    
    // let's make the green view height: 100-points
    let greenHeight: CGFloat = 100.0
    
    // we'll be changing the .constant of the green view's height constraint
    var greenHeightConstraint: NSLayoutConstraint!
    
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        
        // let's add a label and a couple buttons to the green view
        let label = UILabel()
        label.textAlignment = .center
        label.text = "This is sample text for the Header View"
        label.backgroundColor = .yellow
        
        label.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        greenHeaderView.addSubview(label)
        
        let btn1 = UIButton()
        let btn2 = UIButton()
        
        for (b, t) in zip([btn1, btn2], ["Left", "Right"]) {
            b.setTitle(t, for: [])
            b.setTitleColor(.white, for: .normal)
            b.setTitleColor(.lightGray, for: .highlighted)
            b.backgroundColor = .systemRed
            b.layer.cornerRadius = 8
            b.addTarget(self, action: #selector(btnTap(_:)), for: .touchUpInside)
            b.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
            greenHeaderView.addSubview(b)
        }

        greenHeaderView.backgroundColor = .systemGreen
        
        label.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        greenHeaderView.addSubview(label)
        
        greenHeaderView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        tableView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false

        view.addSubview(tableView)

        view.addSubview(greenHeaderView)

        let g = view.safeAreaLayoutGuide
        
        greenHeightConstraint = greenHeaderView.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: greenHeight)
        
        NSLayoutConstraint.activate([
            
            greenHeaderView.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: g.topAnchor),
            greenHeaderView.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: g.leadingAnchor),
            greenHeaderView.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: g.trailingAnchor),

            greenHeightConstraint,
            
            label.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: greenHeaderView.topAnchor, constant: 12.0),
            label.centerXAnchor.constraint(equalTo: greenHeaderView.centerXAnchor),
            
            btn1.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: label.bottomAnchor, constant: 16.0),
            btn1.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: greenHeaderView.leadingAnchor, constant: 20.0),
            
            btn2.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: btn1.topAnchor, constant: 0.0),
            btn2.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: greenHeaderView.trailingAnchor, constant: -20.0),
            
            btn2.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: btn1.trailingAnchor, constant: 20.0),
            btn2.widthAnchor.constraint(equalTo: btn1.widthAnchor),
            
            tableView.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: g.topAnchor),
            tableView.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: g.leadingAnchor),
            tableView.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: g.trailingAnchor),
            tableView.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: g.bottomAnchor),
            
        ])
        
        tableView.register(UITableViewCell.self, forCellReuseIdentifier: "c")
        tableView.dataSource = self
        tableView.delegate = self

        // set tableView's contentInset and contentOffset
        tableView.contentInset.top = greenHeight
        tableView.contentOffset.y = -greenHeight

        // this will prevent the green "header" view's subviews
        //  from showing outside its frame
        greenHeaderView.clipsToBounds = true
        
    }
    
    func scrollViewDidScroll(_ scrollView: UIScrollView) {
        // change the height of the green "header" view
        //  when the tableView scrolls
        //  we don't want a negative height constant
        greenHeightConstraint.constant = max(0.0, -scrollView.contentOffset.y)
    }
    
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return 30
    }
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let c = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "c", for: indexPath)
        c.textLabel?.text = "\(indexPath)"
        return c
    }
    
    @objc func btnTap(_ sender: UIButton) {
        if let str = sender.currentTitle {
            print("Tapped Button with Title: \(str)")
        }
    }
}
```

Result:

[image] [image]

[image] [image]

Comment: It's a working way, thanks 
But there is a small issue, I still have some buttons on the green area, so it should be touchable, but in the way you said, it not touchable

Comment: @martinwotterman - that would have been a good bit of information for your original question. See the **Edit** to my answer.